# jquery ui tabs - how to slide full width of browser window (outside of their container)

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm using jquery ui for tabbed content on this page:  http://dev.triciafrancis.com/mbrstudios/about/

Here's the code I'm now using for tab transitions:

```
$(function() {
    $( ".tabbed-content" ).tabs();
    $( ".tabbed-content" ).tabs( "option", "hide", { effect: "slide", duration: 1000, easing: "easeInOutExpo" } );
    $( ".tabbed-content" ).tabs( "option", "show", { effect: "slide", direction: 'right', duration: 1000, easing: "easeInOutExpo" } );
    $( ".tabbed-content" ).tabs( "option", "heightStyle", "auto" );
});
```

How can I get the tabs to slide in from the right edge of the browser window and out on the left edge?  (Slide full browser as opposed to the width of their container?) I've posted a separate question on how to combine the slide effect with a fade (or any good) effect. The tabs jerk a bit.  Ultimately, I need both solutions to work without conflict.  Any help would be most greatly appreciated!

Comment: I answered, but I don't think it was what you were wanting, so I erased it. I've just moved your code to this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/mapW2/6/ - What do you want to do that is not in the fiddle?

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I need to become more familiar with fiddle... 

I actually made some changes within the page that fixed the full-width scrolling issue.  The only issue I have now is the jerkiness of the slide. Each slide jerks a bit on click of a tab link - and also jerks when coming to a stop.  I've tried various easing methods with no luck. The example in the fiddle is smooth, so it must be something with my page structure?  What am I overlooking?

Comment: I've updated the fiddle to include much more text and two large images http://jsfiddle.net/mapW2/7/. Still no stuttering. What else do you have on the page that is not text or image? Perhaps if you changed the speed of the slide...